# How to replace nth element of a Seq with another Seq element?

Tags: scala

Let's assume we have the following list of items.

```
val utils: Seq[Utilities] = {
  Seq(
    Utilities("jackhammer", 24, "Industrial item", "For sale", "Available"),
    Utilities("axe",        19, "Home item",       "For sale", "Available"),
    Utilities("pick",       39, "Garage item",     "For sale", "Not Available")
  )
}
```

The skeleton class for `Utilities` is as follows:

```
final case class Utilities(item_name: String, ref_id: Int, 
                           item_type: String, sale_status: String, status: String)
```

And we also have another list of items of the current sale status of `Utilities`: (The class does not have any relation with `Utilities`, we only aim to apply its 2nd column into Utilities.)

```
val newAttr: Seq[NewAttributes] = {
      Seq(
        NewAttributes(1,  "For sale"),
        NewAttributes(3,  "Not for sale"),
        NewAttributes(18, "Discontinued")
      )
    }
```

The skeleton class for `NewAttributes` is as follows:

```
final case class NewAttributes(r_id: Int, status: String)
```

How can I replace `Utilities`' *`sale_status`* record with the `NewAttributes` *`status`* in order?

With the new update, `Utilities` shall be like:

```
Utilities("jackhammer", 24, "Industrial item", "For sale",     "Available")
Utilities("axe",        19, "Home item",   "Not for sale", "Available")
Utilities("pick",       39, "Garage item", "Discontinued", "Not Available")
```

I'm successfully retrieving the elements from `newAttr` with the following code, but I've no idea how to apply them to `utils` to achieve the above schema.

```
val prepStatuses = 
   for(na <- newAttr)
      yield na.status
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order is correct it is straight forward:

```
  final case class Utilities(item_name: String, ref_id: Int, item_type: String, sale_status: String, status: String)
  val utils: Seq[Utilities] = {
    Seq(
      Utilities("jackhammer", 24, "Industrial item", "For sale", "Available"),
      Utilities("axe", 19, "Home item", "For sale", "Available"),
      Utilities("pick", 39, "Garage item", "For sale", "Not Available")
    )
  }

  final case class NewAttributes(r_id: Int, status: String)
  val newAttr: Seq[NewAttributes] = {
    Seq(
      NewAttributes(1, "For sale"),
      NewAttributes(3, "Not for sale"),
      NewAttributes(18, "Discontinued")
    )
  }

  utils.zip(newAttr).map{ case(utility, newAttribute) =>
      utility.copy(sale_status = newAttribute.status)
  }
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks, rincewind. Your method worked and could you please explain more about zip if you may?

Comment: Yes sure it just combines each element of the first list with the element in the same position in the second list, creating a tuple of the two elements. For more look here 
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html?search=zip#zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):List[(A,B)]

The length of the new list is always the one of the shorter input list.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to find the data you need:

```
def findStatus(id: Int): Option[String] = 
  newAttr.find(_.r_id == id).map(_.status)
```

And then you need to use that in a for comprehension:

```
val mappedUtils = for(u <- utils)
  yield u.copy(sale_status = findStatus(u.ref_id).getOrElse(sys.error(s"No such id ${u.ref_id}")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by using `zipWithIndex`

```
val zippedNewAttr = newAttr.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
val result = for(x <- utils.zipWithIndex; y = zippedNewAttr(x._2))yield Utilities(x._1.item_name, x._1.ref_id, x._1.item_name, y.status, x._1.status)
```

**Explanation:** 
zipWithIndex generates a Tuple2 where the first value is the original value and the second value is the index of each value. for example `newAttr.zipWithIndex` will produce

```
  (NewAttributes(1, "For sale"),1)
  (NewAttributes(3, "Not for sale"),2)
  (NewAttributes(18, "Discontinued"),3)
```

`_.swap` swaps the above generated tuple2 values and .toMap generates map for each Tuple2 records so `zippedNewAttr` is

```
  (1 -> NewAttributes(1, "For sale"))
  (2 -> NewAttributes(3, "Not for sale"))
  (3 -> NewAttributes(18, "Discontinued"))
```

The *for loop* generates `Utilities` object again but *with the replaced Utilities `sale_status` record with the NewAttributes `status`* and *zipWithIndex preserves the order*.

**Updated**

There is another better approach using iterators

```
val utilsIterator = utils.iterator
val newAttrIterator = newAttr.iterator

val result = ArrayBuffer.empty[Utilities]
while(utilsIterator.hasNext && newAttrIterator.hasNext){
  val utils = utilsIterator.next()
  val newAttr = newAttrIterator.next()
  result.append(Utilities(utils.item_name, utils.ref_id, utils.item_type, newAttr.status, utils.status))
}
```

`result` is the required output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map each `index` of utils to a `copy` of the corresponding utils element with modified sale_status:

```
utils.indices.map(i => utils(i).copy(sale_status = newAttr(i).status))
```